# Unable to Post Data using CURL

Tags: rest, http, curl

I am trying to Change description of My GitHub Account using Curlbut getting error as below:

```
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched brace in column 1
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: description
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: I love development and coding. Like to go deeper and try new things.
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 1
{
  "message": "Not Found",
  "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest"
}
```

The command i am using is below:

```
>curl -X POST -d ' { "description": "I love development and coding. Like to go deeper and try new things. " }'  -u {debbiswas1996@gmail.com:*******} https://api.github.com/users/debbiswas-Git/repos
```

I tried troubleshooting this by below methods but still getting error:

- Tried using without User name and credentials
- Tried escaping the double inverted commas

Can someone please help me here to understand the issue. Thank you for your time.

Comment: It works fine for me

Comment: @HassenCh. Thanks for your reply but still i am facing same issue. Wondering what could be the issue.